# Laravel Homestead make identical local (Windows) and server (Linux)

Tags: javascript, php, homestead

When I uploaded my javascript code to the server much did not work but it works locally. For example, I noticed on the server array variables had to be declared with [] before setting them. Also if I tried looping through an empty array I would get an error on the server. I'm looking at them with both the same browser, Chrome. So does Laravel Homestead make identical local (Windows) and server (Linux) environments to solve this problem? Also is it much toil to get it going? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a PHP question? If so, please fix your tags. Also, this is most likely about the PHP version. The browser doesn't matter when it comes to running PHP scripts, but the PHP version does.

Comment: That is what docker is invented for

Comment: Okay, I took out Homestead and Laravel tags and put in a javascript tag. It is a javascript question rather than a php question since the coding is javascript. However, test and production should behave identically. The only differences in test and production are things like .env files which are not related to this this. If I don't get any ideas I might put the Lravel Homestead tags back in. I appreciate your suggestions, thanks. As for VM Machine software, I don't have enough Linux knowledge to do that. I'm using Cloudways server that does almost everything for you.